# Nginx location redirect regex not working

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to redirect requests to /images/someimage.png on my server to http://some.other.server/images/someimage.png. I have the following in my nginx config:

```
location ^/images/.*(png|jpg|gif)$ {
    rewrite ^/images/(.*)(png|jpg|gif)$ http://anotherserver.com/images/$1$2 redirect;
    return   302;
}
```

But for some reason it isn't getting hit when I request http://test.com/images/test.png (I just get a 404 because that file doesn't exist on myserver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to 302 redirect /image/ url's on one server to the same path on another server. You can do that like so:

```
location /images/ {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://anotherserver.com$request_uri redirect;
}
```

you don't need the `return 302`  the `rewrite ... redirect` already does that 
(if you want 301 redirects instead use `rewrite .... permanent`)

you don't need regexes as long as you have the same url's on the other server either, the builtin variables will suffice

NOTE: 
The reason your location isn't getting hit is that you have `location ^/images/.*(png|jpg|gif)$` instead of `location ~ ^/images/.*(png|jpg|gif)$`. In other words you forgot to signal regex matching (with `~` for case-sensitive or `~*` for case-insensitive)

Comment: Adding ~ did the trick. I wanted to only redirect if it was an image file in that directory.